# Typescript and custom elements properties compilation issue

Tags: javascript, typescript, custom-element

I have this custom elements:

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement{
 constructor(){ super(); }
config: ConfigModel;
}
window.customElements.define('my-element', CustomElement);
```

Then, somewhere in the code, I have something like this:

```
const myElement = document.createElement('my-element');
myElement.config = config;
```

TS throws an error here:
`error TS2339: Property 'config' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.`

Any idea how to solve this issue?

**EDIT:** It was suggested to cast the element's type. While this works, it does poses 2 problems:

1. I don't necessarily want every service that uses the custom element
   to know about the custom element's class
2. If I mock the custom
   element for tests, the hard coded custom element in the service
   won't allow mocking.

Here's the gist that explains it: https://gist.github.com/YonatanKra/de42be2fa5499157169ef141ba377998

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to cast the element to the expected type since Typescript cannot know the type in this scenario.

```
const myElement = <CustomElement>document.createElement('my-element');
```

Also you need to inherit the HTMLElement class in your CustomElement:

```
class CustomElement extends HTMLElement {
```

Edited answer based on further questions:

Obviously if you ever want to access the properties of a `CustomElement` object you would need to type cast. However in all other cases you can just use the default `HTMLElement` type. It should still allow you to perform certain operations on the object, just not anything `CustomElement` related. So not every service needs to know it is a `CustomElement` object.

For mocking you could create a `CustomElementMock` class which inherits from `CustomElement`

```
class CustomElementMock extends CustomElement {
}
```

The mock version is still of type `CustomElement` and your original code should still accept it. However inside the mocked class you could overwrite all functionality to either do nothing or returned mocked data.

Comment: Hi, thanks.
I've forgotten to add the `extends` in my question. Edited to add it.
The casting trick works - but only half way there.
Let's say I'm also testing a service that uses the element, but want to mock it - so in the service I'll use the "real" one, but in the test I'll use the "mock" .
Here's a gist that shows this:
https://gist.github.com/YonatanKra/de42be2fa5499157169ef141ba377998

Comment: Edited to include your other questions. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'm still having an issue when I try this with `@angular/elements`. I could of course create the whole boilerplate that exports the outcome of `createCustomElement`, but I was hoping to avoid that at the beginning of the app (especially when using TDD and just want to test a simple property assignment...).

Comment: Looking at the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/elements) about custom elements they define their elements in a different way. Is there a specific reason the example given by the Angular docs cannot be adjusted to fit your needs?

Comment: Was hoping to avoid more code, but I guess you have to if you want to use TS :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use `document.createElement('my-element') as CustomElement`

Comment: As I've commented, this is not good, since I do not want every service that uses the custom element to know about its class...

Comment: If every service that uses the custom element does not know about it's class, then every service will also not know about the custom property that you have, which is `config`, therefore you have to specify is somewhere, looking at your code example the best way is to specify the return type of the method in the service and perform the above cast.

Comment: This is a bigger problem with angular elements.  In angular elements, the "class" is a component that is converted by @angular/elements to be an HTMLElement.
So I cannot just import the component, I need to import the outcome of angular element's conversion. 
It requires to write a lot of code just to satisfy typescript. I hope it worth it (or that there is a better way to do it).

Comment: Hmm.. I don't know. Can you tell me exactly what the error/exception/failure message in the test is?

Comment: The error is the same, unless I'm handling the whole boilerplate right from the start. This means, that while doing TDD, I'm actually writing tons of code just for the tests to compile.
So I'm writing a simple test for `element.config = config`, but for this test, I'll need to write 2 more tests + implement the methods for them in order to actually get the other test to pass. 
Makes TDD much more cumbersome.

Comment: With angular elements, you have to cast in this manner, `as NgElement & WithProperties<{content: string}>;` https://angular.io/guide/elements I feel like you are diverging and evolving the question a lot, this is where I get off.

Comment: Sorry - was just raising the angular issue as another complication, but thanks a lot. I guess I'll have to code more in order to cope with TS.